# how to use hpn ssh with sftp command

Tags: terminal, command-line, ssh, file-transfer, sftp

I've installed hpn ssh using this command:

```
sudo port install openssh +hpn
```

I want to transfer lost data (100GB at least) using sftp command terminal command.

I am wondering, is installing hpn ssh all I need to do to gain speed advantage with sftp command? After installing hpn ssh, my current upload speed is around 1.8MB (i have a line of 2.5 MB, so that is pretty close). Sadly, I didn't do a test before installing it. stupid me

Also, I noticed that transferring lots of individual files takes a lot more time than transferring 1 big file. Is zipping all the files and than sending that 1 zip the recommended way of transfering to remote host? I would prefer the option to not zip the files first, since zipping 100GB takes some time.

If you know a better solution to transfer large amount of data to remote host, I am open to it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacPorts would install `sftp` in `/opt/local/bin/`. You can test against the OS installed `/usr/bin/sftp`.

The OS installed `zip` uses `gzip compression` by default but can be configured to use `bzip2` (with the -Z option) which should give you better compression. I would split the 100GB of files into smaller archives.

Next, consider using `tar` or `xar` to create your archives. `tar` with `xz` should give you the best compression,`xz` should already be installed by MacPorts. Of course these suggestions depend upon the tools available on the remote host.